# Leibnitz's Theorem proof + intuition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Leibnitz's Theorem.—If $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}a(x)b(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{(n-k)}(x)b^{(k)}(x)$$

How was this derived?
I know there is a proof by induction but I would like to know Leibnitz steps for the discovery of this equation and some intuition.

Comment: I am aslo confused by the book notation C(n,2)?

Comment: You will get terms which contain $n-k$ th order derivatives of $y$ and $k$-th order derivatives of $z$. The coefficient for these terms is a factor which is denoted by $C(n,k)$, since it depends on $n$ and $k$ only. $C(n,0) = 1$ and $C(n,1) =n$ are given explicitly in the formula you have written down.

Comment: @Thomas oh thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you simply multiply the Taylor series for $y$ and $z$ and collect like powers you quickly get a result  that is equivalent to the Leibniz formula. Since Isaac Newton used power series as one of his main tools in his exposition of calculus it would seem likely that Leibniz would know such tricks too.